# using conditionals with presentingViewController in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have some view controllers which are presenting another view controller like so:

```
class LikeDidTapViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Question") as? QuestionViewController {
            if let navigator = navigationController {
                navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In QuestionViewController I need to check which view controller presented it so I can use conditionals to perform various tasks. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can get which is the presenting view controller with viewController.presentingViewController.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller

Comment: It's really poor design. A view controller should never care who presented it. If a view controller needs to behave differently under different conditions, then provide properties that can be set as needed. Then the view controller can act on the state of its properties.

Comment: so QuestionViewController should have a weak var that is set from the presenting viewController?

Comment: Why dont you use a Struct or Globally string that will store Controller detail From which other controller is getting presented like var controllerPresentingFrom = String() and update its value when you are presenting other controller